# How to debug Mailboxer gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, mailboxer

I believe I setup mailboxer gem correctly. Messages work. In my User.rb model I have:

```
  def mailboxer_email(object)
    email
  end
```

However no email gets sent to the receiving user when said user receives a message (I believe by default mailboxer should send this email).

How should I begin debugging this?

Currently, in my messages_controller.rb I have tried manually sending the email:

```
Mailboxer::MessageMailer.new_message_email("You have received a new message.", recipients)
```

But I'm not sure if it's working...